# Baking armature's animation to mesh as keyframes

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, transforms, baking

I basically have an armature with a simple mesh (it's a human body in this case), and I want the mesh to have animated transform with keyframes (not with shapekeys controlled by keyframes). Is there a possible solution for this? I tried exporting and then reimporting as .mdd but that reimports every movement as shapekeys controlled by keyframes.

Comment: Export as Alembic (.abc) and import back.

Comment: afaik it doesn't exisist as is. The tools to deform a mesh are the ones you seem to not want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure this is what you're after but you could try:

In 3d viewport with object selected. Go to object menu > animation> bake to key frames.

Select visual keying and that should bake any animation to key frames. I use it for baking retargeted animations so I'm not sure if it works for animated shape keys but should be worth a try.

Comment: In my case this wouldn't work because the object is parented to the armature, and if I try to bake the object's animation, it does nothing, it'll generate empty keyframes unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Select the mesh, apply transforms, export to PC2 (Point Cache), duplicate the mesh, remove all parenting and all modifiers, add the *Mesh Cache* modifier to the duplicate, select "PC2".